# Image Rotation using ZPL Command

Tags: zpl

How to rotate image by 90 degree using ZPL command
This is the ZPL code that I have written but not able to rotate image by 90 degree.
FO901,60^FR^XGX4BIENes,1,1^FS

This is the ZPL code that I have written
FO901,60^FR^XGX4BIENes,1,1^FS

Comment: ZPL does not provide the ability to rotate images 90 degrees.  You have to rotate the image externally.

Comment: Could you please provide any document link on how to rotate the image externally.

Comment: By rotating the image externally @MarkWarren probably means rotating it using other programming language or other tool before loading the image to ZPL. Currently there is no way to rotate images in ZPL.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Issue is resolved.